# Passing multiple form input fields' data in a child component to its parent in React (hooks)

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, parent-child, react-state

I have a child component that isn't re-rendering because the state inside its parent isn't updating. I've recently found out that I need to pass data from child to parent, but I'm not sure how to do that. Most tutorials I've found on the subject show you how to pass one field or piece of information over to the parent by sending a function, but I have multiple fields on a form I need to send over to the parent component. I'm not sure how to go about that.

Here's the parent component.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useQuery } from "@apollo/client";
import { getStudents } from "../queries";
import StudentDetails from "./StudentDetails";


const StudentList = () => {
  const [student, setStudent] = useState("");
  
  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(getStudents);
  if (loading) return <p>Loading...</p>;
  if (error) return <p>Error!</p>;

  const handleClick = (student)=> {
    //console.log(student)
  
    setStudent(student);
  };
let filteredStudents = [];

//console.log(data.students)

for(let i = 0; i < data.students.length; i++){
  //console.log(data.students[i].class.name)
  if(data.students[i].class.name === "1FE1"){
    //console.log(data.students[i].name)
    filteredStudents.push(data.students[i])
  }
  
}

//console.log(filteredStudents);
  
  return (
    <div>
      <ul id="student-list">
        {data.students.map((student) => (
          <li key={student.id} onClick={(e) => handleClick(student)}>{student.name}</li>
        ))}
        
      </ul>
      {
        student ? <StudentDetails student={student} /> 
        : <p>No Student Selected</p>
        
      }
    </div>
  );
};

export default StudentList;
```

And here is the child component called StudentDetails which displays a student's individual information that isn't re-rendering because StudentList's state isn't changing.

```
import React from "react";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { getStudentQuery } from "../queries";
import { useQuery } from "@apollo/client";
import DeleteStudent from "./DeleteStudent"
import EditStudent from "./EditStudent";


const StudentDetails = (props)=> {
    console.log(props)

    const [astudent, setStudent] = useState(props)
    
    return (
        <div id="student-details" >
            <h2>Name: {props.student.name}</h2>
            <h3>Age: {props.student.age}</h3>
            <h3>Class: {props.student.class.name}</h3>
            <h3>Test 1 Score: {props.student.test1}</h3>
            <DeleteStudent id={props.student.id}/>
            <EditStudent id={props.student.id} />
        </div>
        
    )
    
}

export default StudentDetails;
```

Inside StudentDetails is another child component called "EditStudent" which is where I need to somehow pass the information submitted in the form's fields over to StudentList.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useMutation } from "@apollo/react-hooks";
//import { getStudents } from "../queries";
import StudentDetails from "./StudentDetails";
import { editStudentMutation, getStudentQuery, getStudents } from "../queries/index";


const EditStudent = (props) => {
    console.log(props)
    const [name, setName] = useState(); 
    const [age, setAge] = useState();
    const [test, setTest] = useState();
    const [editStudent] = useMutation(editStudentMutation);

    const astudent = props
    return (
    
        <form id="edit-student" 
            onSubmit={(e) => {
                e.preventDefault();
                editStudent({
                variables: {
                    id: props.id,
                    name: name,
                    age: age,
                    test1: test
                },
                refetchQueries: [{ query: getStudents}]
                });
            }}>
            <div className="field">
                <label>Student Name:</label>
                <input type="text"
                 value={name}
                 onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}/>
            </div>
            <div className="field">
                <label>Age:</label>
                <input type="text"
                 value={age}
                 onChange={(e) => setAge(e.target.value)}/>
            </div>
            <div className="field">
                <label>Test One:</label>
                <input type="text"
                 value={test}
                 onChange={(e) => setTest(e.target.value)}/>
            </div>
            <button>submit</button>
        </form>
    )
}

export default EditStudent;
```

So yeah, I think I understand what I need to do but I don't know where to start on how to pass all the info from EditStudent over to StudentList. As I mentioned, all the tutorials on the subject show how to send one individual piece of information, but not several pieces. Could anyone suggest any pointers on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is lifting a state up; essentially the parent passes a state to the child component and they both can access and change the state. For your case I would suggest passing multiple states down to the child.

Here is an example that does this: [enter link description here](https://codesandbox.io/s/oq587qpno9)